# ИндИанка или индЕанка?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, лексика

Если речь идет об индейцах, а не индийцах, то как правильно писать: "индЕанка" или все равно "индианка"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только индианка. И "речь может идти" и об индийцах, и об индейцах, и даже о индианцах (жителях Индианы):

индианка, -и, р. мн. -нок (к индейцы, индийцы и индианцы)
(Кузнецов, Лопатин)

Слово "индеанка" словарями не фиксируется.
Да оно и невозможно по общим моделям словообразования в русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Оставим в покое "общие модели словообразования в русском языке".
 Но, если  **кто-то** утверждает, что ему  **помнится**  индЕанка в  **одном** орфографическом словаре, то хотелось бы знать: в каком именно?
 Посмотрела во всех ( имеющихся у меня )  **печатных** изданиях:

**индИанка** ( *женск. к* индеец и  *к* индиец )
 Орфографический словарь,  проф. Д.Н.Ушаков,  **1938**

**индИанка** ( *женск. к* индеец и  *к* индиец )
 Орфографический словарь,  проф. Д.Н.Ушаков и доц. С.Е.Крючков,  **1952**

**индИанка**   см. индейцы
 **индИанка**   см. индийцы
 Словарь русского языка в четырёх томах,  том I,  **1957**

**индИанка**  см. индейцы и индийцы
 Толковый словарь русского языка  С.И.Ожегов и Н.Ю.Шведова,  **1996**

А кровь?  Кровь  **индейская**  и  **индийская**.

Answer (score 0):

а почему такое гендерное неравенство? Индеец допустимо, хотя это форма именно русского языка еще дореволюционного времени (индейцы, индеец) , хотя в английском всё одинаково --Indian  Таким образом вводилась разница между этими понятиями Я ТОЧНО видел в справочнике ИНДЕАНКА ГАРАНТИРУЮ!
Не понимаю, при чем здесь правила словообразования? Во главе угла должен стоять здравый смысл
Из "Звезд Голливуда" цитирую : "У Мартина Шина мать была индИанка" (я специально выделил эту букаву) Так какая кровь присутствовала у Мартина Шина: индийская или индейская?